# Spring Data JPA with @OneToOne relation fails to update already persisted entity

Tags: postgresql, unique-constraint, spring-data-jpa, one-to-one

We got this setup: A document has a list of elements and these elements are subclasses of Element, in this example Link. A Link has a @OneToOne relation to Resource. Everything worked as long as we create the whole object graph in one step.

We now changed our code to create an instance of Resource, persist it and pass it to our client (web, objects serialized to JSON). The client creates an instance of the Document and adds a Link with the existing Resource. After that we try to persist the new Document.

At this point the operation fails, because JPA tries to persist the already existing Resource with the same id. I think this happens because the Resource is detached and JPA has no way to determine whether this entity has to be merged or persisted. When I remove the CascadeType.ALL and replace it by CascadeType.MERGE, everything is fine except the Resource is not updated at all.

Basically the workflow is as follows:

- create and persist Resource
- leave transaction
- start transaction
- create Document with Link and (detached) Resource
- error

Is there a problem with our JPA configuration (have a look at our entities)? I'd love to give you a beer sometime if you can give me a hint... :-) TYIA.

Our setup is: EclipseLink 2.4.1, Spring Data JPA 1.3.0 (using @Repository) with PostgreSQL 9.2.

Document:

```
@Entity
public class Document implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @OrderColumn
    @JoinColumn(name = "document_id")
    private List<Element> elements = new ArrayList<Element>();

    // getters and setters
}
```

Element:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.
public class Element implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "document_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Document document;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Link:

```
@Entity
public class Link extends Element {

    @Column
    private String appearance;

    @Column
    private String referenceType;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Resource resource;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Resource:

```
@Entity
public class Resource {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String uri;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I triggered a bug in the EclipseLink implementation. For people who stumble upon the same problems, here a few helpful links:

http://chandanpandey.com/2012/12/22/persisting-a-detached-entity-in-jpa
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=324941

The workaround was to disallow the CascadeType.ALL

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
```

and instead use

```
@OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.DETACH}, orphanRemoval = false)
```

and disable orphanRemoval. This sure has some drawbacks and I hope this will be fixed in are future release of EclipseLink (which I doubt because the bug report is from 2010).

Hope this helps anyone.

Answer (score 1):

The CascadeType.MERGE is meant to cascade merge operation, e.g.:

```
Document document = getDetachedDocumentSomehow();
em.merge(document)
```

to merge whole object graph to persistence context.

What you need to do is to merge your detached Resource instance into persistence context of your second transaction.

```
Resource resource = getDetachedResourceSomehow();
mergedResource = em.merge(resource)
link.setResource(mergedResource)
```

**EDIT:**
Without using entity manager:

```
Resource resource = getDetachedResourceSomehow();
managedResource = resourceDao.findOne(resource.getId)
link.setResource(managedResource)
```

The main point is that you have to set managed instance of Resource.

Comment: But we are using the @Repository functionality from Spring Data JPA because we don't want to write any DAO related code (I'll add this to the question). I am convinced there is a solution for this without manually managing the entities.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Re-attaching the entity is a workaround which I considered, too (and it worked). But in our case changing the annotations as stated in my "answer" was the least awkward solution.